# How can I download multiple photos from Google drive without clicking on each individual photo?

Tags: google-drive

I have over two thousand photos on my Google drive. I would like to download them so I can print them. How can I do this quickly without clicking on each individual photo?

Answer (score 0):

Use the checkbox in the heading row, next to the "Title" heading.  Checking it will select all pictures in the folder, then right click on any of them and select download.  The pictures will download as a single zip archive.
If you just want a subset, click on the checkbox for the first and shift-click on the checkbox for the last one, then right-click and download as an archive.